# Problems with Salesforce Console Integration Toolkit

Tags: visualforce, consoleintegrationtoolkit

My package has a VisualForce page that is used in the OpenCTI Softphone that includes

```
<apex:includeScript value="/support/console/45.0/integration.js"/>
```

I use it for opening records and open the CpenCTI Softphone with

```
sforce.console.setCustomConsoleComponentVisible(true);
```

However, sometimes nothing works. setCustomConsoleComponentVisible or openPrimaryTab doesn't work.

Here I try to open the utility in a developer edition org, but nothing happens.
Calling setCustomConsoleComponentVisible in a developer edition org doesn't work

[image]

Here I try the same in an enterprise ISV org and it works fine.
setCustomConsoleComponentVisible in enterprise ISV org works fine

[image]

I had the same problem yesterday in the enterprise ISV org, but suddenly it worked again after changing nothing in the package.

I tried having a demo today with the package in a sandbox org and it didn't work.